# Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration

Tags: django

In django1.9, tables have been in database already, i create init migration files

```
    python manage.py makemigrations my_app
```

then, i run migrate:

```
    python manage.py migrate my_app
```

It shows:

```
    psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "p_record_segment" already exists
```

I want to fake it, first, i clean the django_migrations, then excute:

```
    python manage.py migrate my_app --fake 0001_initial
```

It shows:

```
    Running migrations:
        Rendering model states... DONE
        Applying my_app.0001_initial... FAKED
```

I think this will be fine, but when i run migrate again:

```
    Running migrations:
      No migrations to apply.
      Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
      Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

I saw the history in django_migrations, and no changes in fact, but why django show me this.

Comment: The message tells you that there is a difference between your current models and your migration files. This has nothing to do with the current state of your database. Try running `manage.py makemigrations` again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `--fake-initial` instead of just `--fake`